# How would you create a page that updates data real time for 10 people in angular?

Tags: angular, observable

I'm trying to figure out the best way to do this. The way I came up with is creating an observable and have it update every second, but I don't know if this is a good idea or not.

Comment: use socket IO with angular

Comment: If you can implement a websocket on server side, it would be the best option. You can easily work with websockets in Angular

Comment: Or use firebase realtime db, it uses websockets as well but should be easy to work with

Comment: thank you! I will check out websockets